# Rails onboarding validations 'suggests' to help users add data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'd like to define **suggestions** in a model the same way you do with validations.

basically, just like validations are a standard practice, i'd like a similar model for onboarding...

```
class Product
  suggest :title, message: "should be between a little bit longer"
  suggests_presence_of :url, :brand, :model, :sku
end
```

then in the view could have:

```
Missing #{model.suggestions.count} suggestions.
We strongly suggest adding url for this product
```

that act almost exactly like a validator but instead just suggest that a user should add something.

Comment: I'm not clear on the use case - when you submit the form, it runs the suggestions then renders the form is any are matched? If this is a UI feature, maybe use something like simple form and hints: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n

Comment: use case: When you login to linkedin, they recommend updating your profile. these would basically be model defined "suggestions" because they aren't required.

Comment: So, it would show a suggestion?  If they've been warned, it would then allow it to go through?

Comment: yes it would show a suggestion if the value doesn't match the `suggest` definition in the model but wouldn't prevent other actions.

Comment: I had exactly the same idea recently... any luck searching that gem ?

Comment: Hi @charlysisto I have added an answer to this question which shows how I solved the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/55732165/1536309

Answer (score 1):

**My Solution:**

Using a custom context (which is built in part of the validation api) has worked well for this use-case:

```
class User < ActiveFoo::Bar
  with_options({on: :onboarding}) do |onboarding|
    onboarding.validates_presence_of :name, message: "You're more likely to be successful with a real name"
    onboarding.validates :bio, length: { maximum: 500 }
    onboarding.validates :registration_number, length: { is: 6 }
  end
end
```

Then to get a list of suggestions do:

```
user.valid?(:onboarding)
```

This makes use of the standard Validations API with a custom context: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on